# How to resolve NaN:NaN:NaN error in Mozilla Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript

I made a countdown for my web page; it works fine all browser except Mozilla and IE.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Below is my code:

```
***var dt = '2018-06-14 11:59 AM';
var ids= 'Demo1';***

function getTimes(dt, ids) {
    var countDownDate = new Date(dt).getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        var op = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
        document.getElementById(ids).innerHTML = op;

        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById(ids).innerHTML = "00:00:00";
            $('a#'+ids).removeClass('a').addClass('aa');
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here, a screenshot of the error;

[image: NaN:NaN:NaN error screenshot]

Comment: use "Numbers" don't use something that's "Not a Number"

Comment: console.log(countDownDate) - it is `NaN`, so distance - NaN ... is NaN ... and distance % anything, is NaN... you need to learn how to use `new Date()` ... i.e. what it can parse ... e.g. ISO 8601 is universally supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs parsing error in IE here:

```
var dt = '2018-06-14 11:59 AM';
var countDownDate = new Date(dt).getTime();
// is not valid date
```

so you have to change the date string format of dt like.

```
var dt = '2018/06/14 11:59 AM';
var countDownDate = new Date(dt).getTime();
// work fine in IE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the date format `2018-06-14` to `2018/06/14`

Answer (score 0):

The `dt` value you accept as an argument is not a number, causing all of those calculations to result in NaN.
We can provide more information if you show how you pass value as `dt` argument to your function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that some browsers (chrome) will accept '2018-06-14 11:59 AM' as a valid date string for `new Date()`. Other browsers (firefox) do not. Your function is trusting the date string as valid when it should either accept a date object that has been pre-verified elsewhere or it should process your specific date string format as if it won't be valid.

Here's an example fix:

```
const dateParts = dt.split(' ')           // ['2018-06-14', '11:59', 'AM']
const timeParts = dateParts[1].split(':') // ['11', '59']
const day = dateParts[0]                  // '2018-06-14'
const hours = parseInt(timeParts[0])      // 11
const minutes = parseInt(timeParts[1])    // 59

var countDownDate = new Date(day)
countDownDate.setHours(hours)
countDownDate.setMinutes(minutes)
```

Edit: changing the source date format is way easier, this solution assumes you can't.

Comment: this case is OK to use `dt = dt.replace(/-/g, '/')` to change the source date format.